# Bind in GridView in a VisualWebPart not evaluated

Tags: visual-web-part, gridview

I have a VisualWebPart with a AspTemplateField that should bind a field but it doesn't

The code is the following:

```
<SharePoint:SPGridView
 ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    AllowSorting="True"
    OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting"
    >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="MyType" DataField="MyType" SortExpression="MyType"/>
         <asp:TemplateField  HeaderText="MyType" SortExpression="MyType">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image id="icon" runat="server" ImageUrl='/_layouts/15/MyProject/images/icons/<%# Bind("MyType") %>' />
                <asp:Label ID="tstlbl" runat="server" Text='/_layouts/15/MyProject/images/icons/<%# Bind("MyType") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>

</SharePoint:SPGridView>
```

Binding is made in c# BehindCode.
What I get is:
-BoundField prints MyType correctly
-asp:Image doesn't print the icon out
-asp:Label prints a string without any translation :

> /_layouts/15/MyProject/images/icons/<%# Bind("MyType") %>

so Bind inside <%#  %> is not evaluated.

Could you tell me why?

Answer (score 2):

This is the code from my project

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlPaging_Top" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnItemCommand="dlPaging_ItemCommand"
                            OnItemDataBound="dlPaging_ItemDataBound">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnPaging" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PageIndex") %>'
                                    CommandName="Paging" Text='<%# Eval("PageText") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:DataList>
```

so try `'<%# Eval("PageText") %>'` and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks but with Eval or Bind the output is the same

Answer (score 1):

You should try as follow. It will work.

```
<SharePoint:SPGridView
ID="GridView1" runat="server"
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
AllowSorting="True">
<Columns>       
     <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlFormatString="~/_layouts/15/MyProject/images/icons/{0}" DataImageUrlField="MyType"></asp:ImageField>    
</Columns>
```

Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use asp.net components and not html

Comment: if you want to use only asp.net components then you need to use asp:ImageField. See my updated answer

Comment: Is you issue resolved?

Comment: Actually, it's not. Because my final intent is that have an image button. Following your advice I tried with ButtonField but it doesn't have  DataImageUrlFormatString so I cannot do as you suggest. At the moment I've passed all path into MyType. This way Bind works. Anyway, if you have another piece of advice I'm all ears